# Executing SQL Stored Procedures with Input and Output parameters

Tags: php, mysql, sql, stored-procedures, pdo

I am very new to stored procedures and the PDO library so please take it easy on me. I am trying to execute a stored procedure using a PDO function and retrieve the recordsets along with the output parameters. Which function should I use and what parameters are necessary?

If I want to execute basic statements using the function like the following example, what PDO method should I use? e.g.

```
$mssql = new mssql;

$mssql->sql('stored_procedure()');
$mssql->sql('SELECT * FROM [test]');
```

**I want the function to return the correct results dependant on the statement type. Is this going to be possible?**

**UPDATE**

Just in case I didnt make it very clear, the 'mssql' class uses the PDO class to execute queries. At the moment I am using:

```
$PDO->prepare();
$PDO->exec();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching around the internet, I found it is in fact very simple using the PDO prepare, bindParam and execute methods.

An example of a store procedure using my class:

```
$mssql->bind_params = array(
    'BatchNum' => array(
        'value' => 'SS000008'
    ),
    'RecCount' => array(
        'value' => 0,
        'type' => PDO::PARAM_INT,
        'length' => 8
    )
);
$mssql->sql("{CALL sp_Batch_Sales(@paramOne=:paramOne,@paramTwo=:paramTwo)}");
```

This is converted to:

```
$query = $PDO->prepare({CALL sp_Batch_Sales(@paramOne=:paramOne,@paramTwo=:paramTwo)});
$query->bindParam(':paramOne',$returned_parameters['paramOne']);
$query->bindParam(':paramTwo',$returned_parameters['paramTwo'],PDO::PARAM_INT,8);
$query->execute();
```

The recordsets can then be retrieved using:

```
do{
    // Get the results
    $results = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    // Only place the results into the array if they exist
    if(!empty($results)){
        $data[$i]['results'] = $results;
    }

    // Set the number of rows in the result array
    $data[$i]['rows'] = $query->rowCount();

    // Increment i
    $i++;
}while($query->nextRowset());
```

And the input and output parameters can be retrieved using the array:

```
$returned_parameters
```

I hope this helps